# How Can I change Carbon Timer To Arabic in laravel

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

how to change carbon time to arabic in laravel THis is A Timer For Sale products

```
data-expire="{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($sale->sale_date)->format('Y/m/d h:m:s') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `local` and `translatedFormat` methods

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($sale->sale_date)->locale('ar')->translatedFormat('Y/M/d h:m:s');
```

the result should be something like

```
"2022/مارس/14 04:03:00"
```

I hope it's helpful

Comment: thank you very much but the data not shownig at all